# How to rename a folder inside a bucket using the AmazonS3.net sdk

Tags: .net, c, amazon-s3

I know that s3 does not really support the folder concept. Copy/Delete all files should work. But maybe somebody knows a simpler way to do this (and I just haven't found it int the SDK)

**Update/Solution:**

The following code is working for me.

```
       using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("xxx",
                                                              "yyy"))
        {

            ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
            listRequest.WithBucketName("ytimusic")
                .WithPrefix("M" + oldOWnerId.ToString()+"/");


            // get all objects inside the "folder"
            ListObjectsResponse objects = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
            foreach (S3Object s3o in objects.S3Objects)
            {

                // get the acl of the object
                GetACLRequest aclRequest = new GetACLRequest();
                aclRequest.WithBucketName("thebucket")
                    .WithKey(s3o.Key);
                GetACLResponse getAclResponse = client.GetACL(aclRequest);


                // copy the object without acl
                string newKey = s3o.Key.Replace(oldOWnerId.ToString(), newOwnerId.ToString());
                CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest();
                copyRequest.SourceBucket = "thebucket";
                copyRequest.DestinationBucket = "thebucket";
                copyRequest.WithSourceKey(s3o.Key)
                .WithDestinationKey(newKey);
                S3Response copyResponse = client.CopyObject(copyRequest);

                // set the acl of the newly created object
                SetACLRequest setAclRequest = new SetACLRequest();
                setAclRequest.WithBucketName("ytimusic")
                    .WithKey(newKey)
                    .WithACL(getAclResponse.AccessControlList);

                SetACLResponse setAclRespone = client.SetACL(setAclRequest);

                DeleteObjectRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest();
                deleteRequest.WithBucketName("thebucket")
                    .WithKey(s3o.Key);

                DeleteObjectResponse deleteResponse = client.DeleteObject(deleteRequest);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 doesn't support neither renaming nor folders, so you actually need to process each file individually by creating a copy with the desired name and deleting the original. To do this with the .NET SDK I'm afraid there is no easier way than listing all files in the directory, and renaming each using CopyObject+DeleteObject. Also, be aware that according to the docs (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectCOPY.html) the copy operation does not preserve the ACL, so if the moved files are public you need to explicitly mark the copies as public as well.

Comment: Thanks. I nearly missed the ACL part. So I have to figure that out as well.

Comment: oops. copying the acl doesn't seem that straightforward.. Do you know how to convert a GetACLResponse.AccessControlList into a CannedACL?

Answer (score 4):

ListObjectResponse only returns 1000 objects by default.  If there are more than 1000 objects, the .IsTruncated property is set to true.  You can change the ListObjectsRequest marker to get the next 1000 objects.  So if your rename operation might effect more than 1000 objects, you could use the following code.

```
public void MoveDirectory(string sourceKey, string destinationKey)
    {

        //Find all keys with a prefex of sourceKey, and rename them with destinationKey for prefix
        try
        {
            DeleteObjectsRequest deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest() {
                BucketName = bucket
            };
            ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest {
                BucketName = bucket,
                Prefix = sourceKey,
            };
            do
            {
                ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = client.ListObjects(listObjectsRequest);
                foreach (var s3Object in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
                {
                    string newKey = s3Object.Key.Replace(sourceKey, destinationKey);

                    CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest() {
                        SourceBucket = bucket,
                        DestinationBucket = bucket,
                        SourceKey = s3Object.Key,
                        DestinationKey = newKey
                    };

                    CopyObjectResponse copyObectResponse = client.CopyObject(copyObjectRequest);
                    deleteObjectsRequest.AddKey(s3Object.Key);
                }
                if (listObjectsResponse.IsTruncated)
                {
                    listObjectsRequest.Marker = listObjectsResponse.NextMarker;
                }
                else
                {
                    listObjectsRequest = null;
                }

            } while (listObjectsRequest != null);

            client.DeleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error Occured with S3 MOVE", amazonS3Exception);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can see to make this code better would be to batch the delete request and fire it off in one shot.

```
        ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
        listRequest.WithBucketName(_bucket).WithPrefix(oldPath);

        DeleteObjectsRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
        deleteRequest.WithBucketName(_bucket);

        // GET ALL OBJECTS UNDER THIS "FOLDER" AND LOOP OVER THEM
        ListObjectsResponse listResponse = _client.ListObjects(listRequest);
        foreach (var obj in listResponse.S3Objects)
        {
            // GET THE ACCESS CONTROL LIST FROM THIS OBJECT BECAUSE COPY PROCEDURES DONT TAKE THIS INTO ACCOUNT
            GetACLRequest aclRequest = new GetACLRequest();
            aclRequest.WithBucketName(_bucket).WithKey(obj.Key);
            GetACLResponse aclResponse = _client.GetACL(aclRequest);

            // GET THE NEW KEY AND COPY THIS OBJECT TO IT
            String newKey = obj.Key.Replace(oldPath, newPath);
            CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest { SourceBucket = _bucket, DestinationBucket = _bucket };
            copyRequest.WithSourceKey(obj.Key).WithDestinationKey(newKey);
            CopyObjectResponse copyResponse = _client.CopyObject(copyRequest);

            // COPY OVER THE ACCESS CONTROL LIST TO THIS "NEW" OBJECT
            SetACLRequest setAclRequest = new SetACLRequest();
            setAclRequest.WithBucketName(_bucket).WithKey(newKey).WithACL(aclResponse.AccessControlList);
            SetACLResponse setAclResponse = _client.SetACL(setAclRequest);

            // ADD THE OLD ITEM TO THE DELETE REQUEST
            deleteRequest.AddKey(obj.Key);
        }

        // DELETE ALL THE OLD OBJECTS IN ONE SHOT TO SAVE ON TRIPS BACK AND FORTH
        _client.DeleteObjects(deleteRequest);
```