# Update File Name on Amazon S3 with IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there is no folder or directory concept on Amazon S3, but I want to update or delete a folder according to my app's users needs.

To Delete folder I guess I have to delete all the files one by one in a folder with:

```
- (S3DeleteObjectResponse *)deleteObjectWithKey:(NSString *)theKey withBucket:(NSString *)theBucket
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonS3Client.html#tasks

But there is no documentation to update a object name
Lets say my folder name is  photos and there are two files in that folder image.png and image2.png  that means I have

```
photos/
photos/image.png
photos/image2.png
```

I want to change folder name to photos1 that means I have to change image.png and image2.png to:

```
photos1/
photos1/image.png
photos1/image2.png
```

How can I accomplish this?

Is this the closest I can get? ([copyObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonS3Client.html#//api/name/copyObject%3a))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. You can't rename a 'folder'. You must process each file individually by creating a copy with the desired name and deleting the original.

Also, be aware that according to the docs (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectCOPY.html) the copy operation does not preserve the ACL, so if the moved files are public you need to explicitly mark the copies as public as well.

Related: [How to rename a folder inside a bucket using the AmazonS3.net sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396224/how-to-rename-a-folder-inside-a-bucket-using-the-amazons3-net-sdk)

Comment: I will check the link and try the solution